# What is a good practice for an additional layer for mongoDB requests

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, layer

What are good practices to have the mongoose request in an other layer as in the controller?

My idea is to have the db request in an other layer as the controller,like in /mongodb/gatewaycontrollers.
So that different controllers can access the same method from the mongodb/gatewayscontrollers/todos.js, instead of repeating the same code in different controllers.

I'm thinking about a structure like this:

```
-controllers
-mongodb
--gatewaycontrollers
--models
-elasticsearch
--gatewaycontrollers
--models
-services
```

Are there any boilerplate examples or tutorial for that?

Comment: I think You look for best practices for express + mongoose app. Check this: https://github.com/num8er/alttab-nodejs-challenge

Comment: Hy num8er. Thanks for the link. I gonna check that out.